# Error creating table: Incorrect table name

Tags: php, html

I cannot access the textbox content to create the table in Mysql and the error is 
**"Error creating table: Incorrect table name ''**

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","abc");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$email` (
`id` INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`firstname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(50),
`regdate` TIMESTAMP
 )";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
 } else {
 echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
 }

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Your question title and the body of your question appear unrelated. Please edit your question to make your question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If error is "Error creating table: Incorrect table name" and you query has:

```
CREATE TABLE `$email`
```

Most probably `$email` has an `@` sign in it, that shouldn't be part of a table name - use only [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore).

It is not likely that a table should be created each form sublimation, and that its name should be dynamic (you will not know it to query data from this table).

Not less important - never use user input directly in your SQL (to avoid SQL injection). Reference: 
[PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements Tutorial to Prevent SQL Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I need code for textbox values to create database in Web page, but my code is not working and any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows-

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $email(
`id` INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`firstname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(50),
`regdate` TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Comment: I need  code for  textbox values to create database for signin Web page

Comment: that means the table name will be what you enter in textbox right?

Comment: I have modified the answer